# Create a NEW TABLE from rows checked in an existing table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table of items with a checkmark disclosure button, and I want to create a second table based off which of those are checked. I know I'm supposed to use the method **tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath**, but I have no clue how to implement it.

So let's say this is my code, where do I enter the **ButtonTapped** method and how is it implemented?

```
@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize detailViewController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self createFlowerData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

// Ensure that the view controller supports rotation and that the split view can therefore show in both portrait and landscape.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Size for popover
// The size the view should be when presented in a popover.
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopoverView {
    return CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [flowerSections count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[flowerData objectAtIndex:section] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[[[flowerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[[flowerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"]]];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [flowerSections objectAtIndex:section];
}


- (void)createFlowerData {

    NSMutableArray *redFlowers;
    NSMutableArray *blueFlowers;

    flowerSections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"Red Flowers",@"Blue Flowers",nil];

    redFlowers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    blueFlowers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [redFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Poppy",@"name",
                           @"poppy.png",@"picture",
                           @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy",@"url",nil]];
    [redFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tulip",@"name",
                           @"tulip.png",@"picture",
                           @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip",@"url",nil]];
    [redFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Gerbera",@"name",
                           @"gerbera.png",@"picture",
                           @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbera",@"url",nil]];
    [redFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Peony",@"name",
                           @"peony.png",@"picture",
                           @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peony",@"url",nil]];
    [redFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Rose",@"name",
                           @"rose.png",@"picture",
                           @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose",@"url",nil]];
    [redFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hollyhock",@"name",
                           @"hollyhock.png",@"picture",
                           @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollyhock",
                           @"url",nil]];
    [redFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Straw Flower",@"name",
                           @"strawflower.png",@"picture",
                           @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawflower",
                           @"url",nil]];

    [blueFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hyacinth",@"name",
                            @"hyacinth.png",@"picture",
                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_(flower)",
                            @"url",nil]];
    [blueFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hydrangea",@"name",
                            @"hydrangea.png",@"picture",
                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrangea",
                            @"url",nil]];
    [blueFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sea Holly",@"name",
                            @"seaholly.png",@"picture",
                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_holly",
                            @"url",nil]];
    [blueFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Grape Hyacinth",@"name",
                            @"grapehyacinth.png",@"picture",
                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grape_hyacinth",
                            @"url",nil]];
    [blueFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Phlox",@"name",
                            @"phlox.png",@"picture",
                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlox",@"url",nil]];
    [blueFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Pin Cushion Flower",@"name",
                            @"pincushionflower.png",@"picture",
                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scabious",
                            @"url",nil]];
    [blueFlowers addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Iris",@"name",
                            @"iris.png",@"picture",
                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(plant)",
                            @"url",nil]];

    flowerData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                redFlowers,blueFlowers,nil];

    [redFlowers release];
    [blueFlowers release]; 
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    return 75.0;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     When a row is selected, set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
     */
    detailViewController.detailItem = 
         [[flowerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] 
          objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [flowerData release];
    [flowerSections release];
    [detailViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Ultimately I want it something like in this image, where the items checked off on the right appear as a new table on the left:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried but this should get you well on your way to solve your problem:

1. Create a NSMutableArray to hold your selected rows: `selectedRowsArray`
2. Implement `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method:
3. Inside this method, get a reference to the selected cell with `UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.
4. Check if the cell already has a checkmark in it, if NO, add the checkmark and add the object you are interested in to the mutable array...

Ex:

```
if (cell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selectedRowsArray addObject:THE_OBJECT];
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [selectedRowsArray removeObject:THE_OBJECT];
}
```

Now you can use the mutable array to populate the other tableview with data. Remember to call `reloadData` on the tableview every time you add or remove an object from the array.

Comment: Oh and you may need to set your cell selection style to none or programatically deselect the cell once it is tapped.